# How do I know if DropBox has finished uploading my files from the web interface?

Tags: dropbox

I've started to upload to my DropBox a couple of big files this morning from home before going to work.

Now I'm at work and I don't have the client installed but I can access the web interface. Looking through the web interface, I'm wondering if my uploads are complete. (I don't have remote access to my home computer either.)

Is there a way to know if the upload is complete, or is it just *"if the like looks normal, it's because the upload is complete"* type of things?

The [documentation](https://www.dropbox.com/help/406) is quite clear with the client file status icons, but I haven't found anything regarding the web interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the name of the file, the [Events tab](https://www.dropbox.com/events) in Dropbox's web interface will tell you when the file finished uploading. The file will not show up in Events until it is uploaded completely.

Comment: Or you could just browse the folder that your expect the file to be in. If it is there, you know the upload is complete. If it is not there, the upload has not finished.